PowerBI - Group by Count with Detail?
I am trying to get a table put together, and shows the # of Policies, and then the # of Users that makes up that policy count.
My table, basically, is as follows:
User    Policy #
A       67728
A       86440
A       38497
B       11959
C       53988
C       36813
C       38102
B       3030
Z       90934
X       50008
Y       97409

So, I can see that User A has 3 policies. User B has 2 policies, User C has 3, and then users X, Y, and Z each have one.
How can I create a table that shows the # of Policies along the left, and then the # of users that make up that group?
# Policies  Total Users
1           3
2           1
3           2

This way, I can see that there are 3 users each having 1 policy.  There's only 1 user with two policies, etc.  It would be a bonus if I could then expand on the "Total Users" and it shows me more detail, e.g. the users in that group.
Note that the data may have users with more than 3, so I can't "hard code" the groups into 1, 2, 3, etc.  It should be "dynamic".
I am quite good in Excel but am relatively new to PowerBI/DAX expressions so I'm not sure even where/how to begin.

Was your problem solved?

This is an easy way to do static segmentation. If you want dynamic segmentation, then see here.

Policy Count = 
VAR user = 'Table'[User]
RETURN
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), 'Table'[User] = user, REMOVEFILTERS()) 

Create a measure:
Measure = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[User])

Create table 1:

Create table 2:

Table 1 will now filter table 2 when you click on a bucket.

When I do this as a New Measure, VAR user = 'Table1'[User] gives me an error, and says that "A single value for column 'User' in table 'Table1' cannot be determined..."?

That is a calculated column

What does that mean? that User is a calculated column? Is that something I fix by changing the Data Type?

The Policy count is a calculated column and not a measure. Click on the table and create it

Thank you, and thanks @AmiraBedhiafi for that clarification, that did the trick.  Note: I have a filter on all pages, and replaced REMOVEFILTERS() with FILTER(table, filter formula).  Is there a way to reference the page filter, instead of having to type it explicitly into the calculated column formula, if that makes sense?
